# Django. Business Logic Bottlenecks.

Tags: python, django, performance, view

Is there any smart way to find bottlenecks in business logic. For example, we have application, that have one view that doing HttpResponse('1') in big project. We are sure, that no SQL queries in middlewares exists. But HttpResponse working really slow(50 rps vs 200 rps on clear django project).

1. What reasons can be?
2. How to find bottlenecks in this case?
3. Also we know, that in clear project less than 1 Mb of memory used for objects on each request, and in our project - more than 2Mb. How to find these objects?

Comment: [This](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ProfilingDjango) might help you.

Comment: I've taken a look at his already.

Comment: Are you tried django debug-toolbar?

Comment: Django debug toolbar shows query count on each page. Also it's useful to see how much cache hits/misses, and which templates are used. But here performance problems happens before view and model logic starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug toolbar works well, but I also like running django-devserver.  It can give you more information than you can process sometimes.

```
DEVSERVER_MODULES = (
    'devserver.modules.sql.SQLRealTimeModule',
    'devserver.modules.sql.SQLSummaryModule',
    'devserver.modules.profile.ProfileSummaryModule',

    # Modules not enabled by default
    'devserver.modules.ajax.AjaxDumpModule',
    #'devserver.modules.profile.MemoryUseModule',
    'devserver.modules.cache.CacheSummaryModule',
    #'devserver.modules.profile.LineProfilerModule',
)
```

This is what modules I have turned on, and one hit to the admin page after start:

```
Django version 1.3.1, using settings 'myproject.settings' Running django-devserver 0.3.1 Threaded django server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
    [sql] SELECT ...
      FROM "auth_message"
      WHERE "auth_message"."user_id" = 1
    [sql] SELECT ...
      FROM "django_admin_log"
      INNER JOIN "auth_user" ON ("django_admin_log"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id")
      LEFT OUTER JOIN "django_content_type" ON ("django_admin_log"."content_typ_id" = "django_content_type"."id")
      WHERE "django_admin_log"."user_id" = 1
      ORDER BY "django_admin_log"."action_time" DESC LIMIT 10
    [sql] 4 queries with 0 duplicates
    [profile] Total time to render was 0.54s
    [cache] 0 calls made with a 100% hit percentage (0 misses) [30/Nov/2011 08:36:34] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 21667 (time: 0.69s; sql: 0ms (4q))
    [sql] SELECT ...
      FROM "django_flatpage"
      INNER JOIN "django_flatpage_sites" ON ("django_flatpage"."id" = "django_fatpage_sites"."flatpage_id")
      WHERE ("django_flatpage"."url" = /favicon.ico/
             AND "django_flatpage_sites"."site_id" = 1)
    [sql] 1 queries with 0 duplicates
    [profile] Total time to render was 0.02s
    [cache] 0 calls made with a 100% hit percentage (0 misses) [30/Nov/2011 08:36:34] "GET /favicon.ico/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2587 (time:
0.89s; sql: 0ms (1q))
```

Comment: Helped me to find hidden queries on first request to django.

Comment: Yeah, really helps when you start overriding save's and signaling between models to make sure things are happening in the correct sequence on the database.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the django debug toolbar ? You could find what queries are run with it, middleware or not.
How do you monitor the performance of the view ?
Are there **much** more users in the big project than in the fresh one ?

Comment: Django debug toolbar commonly about sql queries. For view performance monitoring we use pycallgraph + pympler.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your bottle neck is not in your or the django code. What webserver do you use, and how many requests are handled by the worker processes?

If you use mod_wsgi be sure to have enough worker processes and that maximum-requests is high.

And of course be sure that settings.DEBUG is not set.

Apache logs can include the request process time in microseconds: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html check for %D

Check in your middleware how long the interpreter is inside your+django code.

```
# Middleware to check how long the request was in the wsgi queue:
class FooMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request):
        ...
        queue_start=request.META.get('HTTP_X_QUEUE_START', None)
        if queue_start is not None:
            # How long was the request waiting in the wsgi queue?
            # In Apache Config: 
            # RequestHeader add X-Queue-Start "%t" (in <VirtualHost>)
            queue_start = int(queue_start[2:])/1000000.0
            wait_in_queue=time.time()-queue_start
            if wait_in_queue>1:
                logging.error('Request was too long  (%.3fs) in wsgi-queue: %s' % (
                        wait_in_queue, request.build_absolute_uri()))
```

Comment: Worth pointing out is that the New Relic Python agent also looks for HTTP_X_QUEUE_START in WSGI environ dictionary and New Relic will show queuing time in its overview charts. See my answer for links to New Relic.

Answer (score 0):

You could try New Relic and see if it helpful in narrowing down problem area.

- http://newrelic.com/python
- http://blog.newrelic.com/2011/11/08/new-relic-supports-python/

Good thing is that you can use it on a production application where Django debug toolbar you cant.